# Image horizontal reel scroll dynamic slideshow for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

Is anyone know how to create a horizontal reel scroll slideshow in asp.net as in the following link!

[link of Live Demo horizontal slide show for WordPress](http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need Jquery with this, there are lots of sliders around.

Simple and easy that suits your requirement is this
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-image-scroller/

Demo for above 
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/300_jquery/image%20Scroller/imageScroller.html

You need to bind images at load of a page to the slider and Jquery will take care of the rest.

Comment: thanks...I have got it from this link, it was cool [CoolScroller](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/57/)

Comment: ...Do something for this link, or send it to some one you know that he can give an idea or solution.... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849546/getting-the-exact-edited-data-from-sql-server)